# AngularJS orderBy child property not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

How can I order the list of items by the child property `"active" : true`? The first node is a dynamically inserted id for every friend.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="friend in friends|orderBy:'friend.active':true">
        <span class="name">{{friend.name}}</span>
        <span class="phone">{{friend.lastName}}</span>
</li>

$scope.friends = {
    "12345": {
        "name": "Dhiraj",
        "lastName": "Agarwal",
        "active" : false
    },
    "23456": {
        "name": "Poonam",
        "lastName": "Mittal",
        "active" : false
    },
    "34567": {
        "name": "Suresh",
        "lastName": "Bansal",
        "active" : true
    },
    "45678": {
        "name": "Usha",
        "lastName": "Goel",
        "active" : false
    }
};
```

Comment: instead of `friend.active` , can you try `"friend in friends | orderBy: 'active': true"` ?

Comment: orderBy is used with arrays, not objects.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution at

http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/

and

github.com/fmquaglia/ngOrderObjectBy

Created a new filter and then used to order it

plnkr : plnkr.co/edit/4eCq7yaVyXGZB8etLZhN?p=preview

```
<li data-ng-repeat="friend in friends|orderObjectBy:'active':true">

app.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
  return function(items, field, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      filtered.push(item);
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      return (a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
    });
    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Comment: I posted an other solution, take a look ;)

Answer (score -1):

Regular ng-filter orderBy accepts only array.

Using this kind of data works fine:

```
 $scope.friends = [{
            "name": "Dhiraj",
                "lastName": "Agarwal",
                "active": false

    },  {
            "name": "Poonam",
                "lastName": "Mittal",
                "active": false

    },{
            "name": "Suresh",
                "lastName": "Bansal",
                "active": true

    }, {
            "name": "Usha",
                "lastName": "Goel",
                "active": false

    }];
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jbigman/mhw8pede/)

EDIT:
If you don't want to use an array, you can use the workaround described in this angular [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1286)

The filter (not perf tuned and using underscore):

```
app.filter('toArray', function() { return function(obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Object)) return obj;
    return _.map(obj, function(val, key) {
        return Object.defineProperty(val, '$key', {__proto__: null, value: key});
    });
}});
```

Example markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="val in object | toArray | orderBy:'priority' | filter:fieldSearch">
  {{val.$key}} : {{val}} 
</div>
```

Comment: In your solution you have removed the keys associated with every object. It is not possible to remove those keys in my implementation.